# select where a and next is c, skipping b

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am wondering if it is possible in SQL to return a single row to show, using the table below as an example, only a row for id 2:

```
table1  ( id 2 and 4 are missing value b)
id      value
1         a
1         b
1         c
1         d
2         a
2         c
2         d 
3         a
3         b
3         c
3         d
4         a
4         c
4         d
```

i basically want to find all instances where 'b' does not exist but 'a' still does exist for any id and return a single row for that any given id. i have tried something like this, but its not working as i would want it to:

```
select * from table1 
    where not exists (select distinct value from table1 where value b)
```

i would like the end result to be something this, identifying the values where 'b' does not exist but 'a' does(not showing the value, is unneeded for final goal):

```
result table
id        
2           
4
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate rows in the table, i.e. more than one row containing ( 42, 'a' )?

Comment: yes there can, i forgot that detail sorry. although im not sure it would affect the results based on the answers given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
select distinct id
from table1 t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from table1 tt 
    where t.id = tt.id and tt.vallue = 'b'
)  
and exists (
    select 1
    from table1 tt 
    where t.id = tt.id and tt.vallue = 'a'
)
```

Below you have shorter form. It may perform better and distinct keyword may be unnecessary if the pair (id, value) is unique.

```
select distinct id
from table1 t
left join table1 tt
on t.id = tt.id and tt.value = 'b'
where t.value = 'a' 
and tt.id is null
```

Comment: they pair is not unique, but thank you for the alternative. ill remember if i need to come back to this question any time

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id
FROM table1 t1
WHERE 
    value = 'a'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table1 sub
        WHERE sub.id = t1.id AND sub.value = 'b'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested, but I think something like this would work.

```
SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE value='a' AND id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE value='b') 
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Apologies to Dooh.  I just noticed that this answer is essentially a duplicate of Dooh's second query.  I'll leave it as a runnable example.

It may be enlightening to compare execution plans for the various queries.

```
declare @table1 as table ( id int, value varchar(10) )
insert into @table1 ( id, value ) values
  ( 1, 'a' ), ( 1, 'b' ), ( 1, 'c' ), ( 1, 'd' ),
  ( 2, 'a' ), ( 2, 'c' ), ( 2, 'd' ),
  ( 3, 'a' ), ( 3, 'b' ), ( 3, 'c' ), ( 3, 'd' ),
  ( 4, 'a' ), ( 4, 'c' ), ( 4, 'd' ),
  ( 5, 'a' ), ( 5, 'a' ), ( 5, 'b' ), -- Duplicate 'a's.
  ( 6, 'a' ), ( 6, 'a' ) -- Duplicate 'a's.

select distinct L.id
  from @table1 as L left outer join
    @table1 as R on R.id = L.id and R.value = 'b'
  where R.id is NULL and L.value = 'a'
```